# Is it normal to flag a question, and answer it anyway?

Tags: discussion, reputation, closed-questions

Is it normal to flag a question, and answer it anyway? If one earns reputation for an answer, but then the question closed because of a flag, will your reputation decrease too?

Comment: @AnnZen that's what comments are for. Something along the lines of: "I think you're after XYZ but it's not entirely clear if that's the case. Would you mind clarifying?". Then if they answer one way or the other and don't edit the post then you can always remind them with something like: "Great thanks! Please can you edit your post to include that information"...

Comment: I sometimes had the case that I did not know that a duplicate existed, then someone else suggested one after I added the answer. That's the only reasonable case I could think of, were both a vote gets casted and an answer gets added.

Comment: answer it, when you can. you might lose the gained points though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not usual to both flag and answer. If you're flagging then something is wrong with the post and you're signalling it probably shouldn't be answered. Maybe it should be deleted (spam/rude) or just closed till it can be edited into a state where it can be answered.

Flagging that a question needs attention and then guessing at what the asker wanted and answering that guess is often likely to lead to a waste of your time, you should probably move on to a question you can answer while waiting for that question to be edited into shape. If that never happens then so be it, it's unlikely to help anyone else either if it's unclear.

You can always leave a comment, if you feel it might help the asker reshape the question e.g. "I think you're looking for something like this... if you edit your question to confirm I can flesh that out into an answer for you."

Closure does not affect reputation, only deletion. If a post is deleted then unless it scored > 3 and is more than 60 days old any reputation you gained or lost from it will disappear.